# MySQL combine column

Tags: mysql, join, left-join

I have 2 tables that reference each other. First table is position.

```
id      title   
------  --------
001     a       
002     b       
003     c       
004     d       
005     e
```

and the second table is unit.

```
id      status  info        
------  ------  ------------
001     s       manager     
001     o       head manag  
002     s       programmer  
003     s       programmer
```

in status field, 's' means header, and 'o' means body.
I have try with left join with no luck.

```
SELECT a.id, a.title, 
(CASE WHEN b.status = 's' THEN b.info END) AS header, 
(CASE WHEN b.status = 'o' THEN b.info END) AS body
 FROM 
POSITION a LEFT JOIN
 unit b
ON a.id = b.id
```

result is

```
id      title   header      body        
------  ------  ----------  ------------
001     a       manager     (NULL)      
001     a       (NULL)      head manag  
002     b       programmer  (NULL)      
003     c       programmer  (NULL)
```

I wonder the result is like this

```
id      title   header      body        
------  ------  ----------  ------------
001     a       manager     head manag
002     b       programmer  (NULL)      
003     c       programmer  (NULL)
```

thanks in advance.

Comment: What about if there is another entry for the title 'a'?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to GROUP BY id. And you need an aggregate function (like `MIN()` or `MAX()`) for the status column.

```
SELECT a.id, a.title, 
MIN(CASE WHEN b.status = 's' THEN b.info END) AS header, 
MIN(CASE WHEN b.status = 'o' THEN b.info END) AS body
 FROM 
POSITION a LEFT JOIN
 unit b
ON a.id = b.id
GROUP BY a.id
```

[sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/46fd5b/4)

**Update:**

Let's take your original result without aggregation but limit it only to id = 001

```
id      title   header      body        
------  ------  ----------  ------------
001     a       manager     (NULL)      
001     a       (NULL)      head manag
```

Now if you group the result by id (`GROUP BY a.id`) but don't use any aggregate function, MySQL is free to choose any value* from columns that are not listed in the GROUP BY clause. That is not an issue for the `title` column**, because it should always be the same. But for `header` and `body` columns MySQL may choose NULL. Using `MIN(...)` we tell MySQL to choose the "smallest" value that is NOT NULL (or NULL if only NULL "values" exist). It doesn't matter if you use `MIN()` or `MAX()`, because there should only be one not null value and the result would be the same.

```
hedaer:
    MIN('manager', NULL) = 'manager'
    MAX('manager', NULL) = 'manager'

body:
    MIN(NULL, 'head manag') = 'head manag'
    MAX(NULL, 'head manag') = 'head manag'
```

---

* In fact it will choose the first value. But that is a question of implementation and this behaviour may be changed in the future.

** In strict mode you are not even allowed to select `title` because it is not listed in the GROUP BY clause. So you would either need to use an aggregate function (`MIN(a.title)`) or list it in the GROUP BY clause (`GROUP BY a.id, a.title`).

Comment: super, I even never use min or max, when I have to use min and max actually?

Comment: now I get it. Even your explanation better than mysql documentation. Thanks in advance.